# ASP MVC application deploy problems with Jquery

Tags: jquery, deployment, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

I'm deploying a simple asp mvc 2 application on my local IIS 7.5 server.
But when I try to run some javascript

```
    
            $(function () { alert("works"); })
```

in view or Site.Master, I do not see any alert. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be a couple of problems

```
 $(function () {
   alert("works");
   });   <--------- you are missing a semi colon
```

make sure you have included the `jquery`

if you are loading `jquery` from the google cdn it might be possible that its blocked on the server in that case reference to the `jquery.js` saved on your server

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" after putting semicolon, by the way: I don't think the semicolon does any matter in this case.

Comment: @Nozim yes the problem is you have not included the jquery in your project

Comment: I solved the problem with referencing to google libraries but, I want to have my dependencies satisfied locally.

Comment: then download the jquery and reference from your local server location